# Norm on a certain quotient C$^*$-algebra

Tags: c-star-algebras

Let $\{A_i\}_{i\in I}$ be an arbitrary family of C$^*$-algebras, we may define their product as
$$\prod_{i\in I}A_i=\{(a_i);~\sup_{i\in I}\|a_i\|<\infty\}.$$
We can also define 
$$\sum_{i\in I}A_i=\{(a_i);~\text{For any }\epsilon>0\text{ there only finitely many }i\in I\text{ for which }\|a_i\|\geq \epsilon\},$$
which can be shown to be the closure of the collection of those $(a_i)$ in the product which have only finitely many non-zero entries. $\sum_I A_i$ is a closed (two   sided) ideal in $\prod_I A_i$ and we can form the quotient 
$$Q:=\prod_{i\in I} A_i/\sum_{i\in I} A_i.$$
In the blue book "An Introduction to K-Theory for C$^*$-algebras" (Lemma 6.1.3) it is shown that when $I=\mathbb{N}$, the norm on $Q$ is given by 
$$\|[(a_n)]\|=\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}\|a_n\|,$$
where $[(a_n)]$ denotes the coset of $(a_i)$. My question is does this statement generalise? Say if $I$ is a directed set, then would it be true that
$$\|[(a_i)]\|=\limsup_{i\in I}\|a_i\|?$$
Prahlad's answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2101515/inductive-limits-of-c-algebras/2102443#2102443) seems to say that yes, this is true, but I have only succeeded in making minimal progress on this. Mimicking the proof given in the blue book, I have shown that $\|[(a_i)]\geq \limsup_I\|a_i\|$, but I am failing to see how the reverse inequality can be derived.